# React / Redux: single source of truth when navigating into a details view

Tags: redux, react-redux

I have an architectural / best practices question regarding react and redux.

I'm using redux middleware to query a graphql service and expose the result in props to connected components. One of the advantages of graphql is being able to retrieve only the information you need using their query format.

I have a page that lists entities and when you click a specific entity you get a view entity detail page with the id in the query string.

I want an array of entities in my state to be my single source of truth and a selectedEntityId property to serve as a lookup on that list of entities.

My problem is that the list of entities in the list page is just the name and description while the view page contains much much more information.

**Solutions I can think of:**

1) Retrieve all the entities information (not just name and description) in the list page (and view page). The problem is that I'd be querying a bunch of information I don't need on the list page which goes against the idea of graphql.

2) Have 2 properties on my state. One will contain entities with just name and description while the other property will contain a list of entities with more information. The problem with this solution is that I have 2 single sources of truth.

3) I can "marry" the 2 entity lists, so if I navigate from a list to a view page, I can saturate the list of entities I already have from the list page with the entities I get from the view page (the entities with many more properties besides name and description) and use that list as my single source of truth. This seems to be the best solution but I don't know a clean way to do this.

Can anyone shed light on the situation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if thats the best one, but based on your solutions, I would say the third works alright.

You could try adding a new value to each list item that identifies if the specific item has all the details or not.

Imagine the store like so:

```
items: {
  id1: {
    isFull: false,
    title: 'Item 1',
    id: 'id1'
  },
  id2: {
    isFull: true,
    title: 'Item 2',
    id: 'id2',
    description: '..',
    lorem: '',
    ...
  }
}
```

Then get `isFull` in the details page and fetch in case of false.